# Regex to change method call parameter

Tags: regex, replace, coda

Regexs make me cry, so, I came here for help.

I'm looking for some tips on Find & Replace in [Panic's Coda](http://panic.com/coda). I know the F&R
is pretty advance but I'm just looking for the best way to do this.
I'm trying to rewrite a 'template engine' (very basic) I have going on with a
webapp I'm coding in PHP (CodeIgniter).

Currently I'm calling my template like so:

```
$this->load->view('subviews/template/headerview');
$this->load->view('subviews/template/menuview');
$this->load->view('subviews/template/sidebar');
$this->load->view('The-View-I-Want-To-Load');   // This is the important line
$this->load->view('subviews/template/footerview');
```

However it's inefficient using five lines of code every time I want to
load up a different page, in every different controller. So I rewrote it like this:

```
$data['view'] = 'The-View-I-Want-To-Load';
$this->load->view('template',$data);
```

That way if I need to make any major changes to the design it can
easily be done from the template.php view file (which contains the header, menu, sidebar views etc. etc.).

However I use the previous 5-lines all over the place in many
different controllers and functions. So, my question is --- How can I
find and replace the old template engine (5 lines of code) for the new
one - substituting in the name of the view in the important, unique
line for the one in $data['view]?

Does that make any sense?! If not I'll try and rephrase! I mean, is there a way of doing this via a Regex or something? Or am I on completely the wrong lines here?

Comment: Do these five lines always occur in the same order? Or, in other words, how do I know which one of them contains the view you want to load?

Comment: They always occur in the same order. The fourth line always contains the view I want to load into the main content area. So the fourth line is the dynamic one, otherwise lines 1, 2, 3 and 5 always remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regex will look something like this :

```
\$this->load->view\('subviews/template/headerview'\);\n\$this->load->view\('subviews/template/menuview'\);\n\$this->load->view\('subviews/template/sidebar'\);\n\$this->load->view\('([^']*)'\);\n\$this->load->view\('subviews/template/footerview'\);
```

and replace with

```
\$data['view'] = '$1';\n\$this->load->view('template',\$data);
```

Comment: Nice one! I'll test it on a sample PHP file first and report back shortly.

Comment: My bad, haven't had enough coffee this morning. Wasn't in Regex mode, I'll try again! :D

Comment: depending on the software, you might need to double-escape the \ chars. i think i got them all escaped properly, but it's still the morning for me too :P

Comment: Haha, no worries :) OK, in Coda, this still doesn't find anything with Regex turned on. I have several options: Syntax (Java, Perl, Ruby, GNU, grep, POSIX, POSIX Basic, etc.) - it's set to Ruby by default. Escape Character is set to \. What's next?! I'm pretty confused here...

Comment: And possibly use `\r\n` if you're on a Windows system.

Comment: are there any tabs/spaces? you could replace the \n in the search string with \n\s* instead, which will replace any number of whitespaces after the linebreak.

Comment: good stuff, glad i could help. regexp's are awesome for this type of code maintenance.